# sublime theme in project settings

Tags: sublimetext3

I have some projects. I have several windows open at the same time and I get confused in them.
Is it possible in the project settings to set for each project its own theme (design)?
try

```
    {
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "server"
        },
        {
            "path": "sources"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "tab_size": 4,
        "save_on_focus_lost": true,
        "theme": "Adaptive.sublime-theme"
    }
}
```

its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you cannot customise the theme per project, but you might have some luck with your problem by customising the colour scheme instead. It goes under the `settings` section where you tried to put the `theme`. So your `.sublime-project` file may look something like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/my/project/"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "color_scheme": "Packages/Visual Studio Dark/Visual Studio Dark.tmTheme",
    }
}
```

Hope that works out for you ‍‍

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to customize the Theme per window, no. Specifically, project specific settings can only include `Editor Settings` and not `User Interface Settings` or `Application Behaviour` Settings.

When you open the preferences window, the left pane contains the Default settings file. The settings at the top of the file are `Editor` settings; there is a clear delineation via comment that shows when the `User Interface` and `Application Behaviour` start.

```json
    // When drag_text is enabled, clicking on selected text will begin a
    // drag-drop operation. This is not currently implemented under Linux.
    "drag_text": true,

    //
    // User Interface Settings
    //

    // The theme controls the look of Sublime Text's UI (buttons, tabs, scroll bars, etc)
    "theme": "Default.sublime-theme",
```

```json
    // Magnifies the entire user interface. Sublime Text must be restarted for
    // this to take effect. 1.0 is normal scale, 0.0 allows for auto-detection
    // based on text scale with older Linux configurations that don't fully
    // support GTK display scaling.
    "ui_scale": 0.0,

    //
    // Application Behavior Settings
    //

    // Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
    // immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
    // be preserved and restored when next starting.
    //
    // Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
    // without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
    // alongside the project.
    "hot_exit": true,
```

The `theme` setting is the first `User Interface` setting and is thus not allowed in project specific settings. You can however make the windows visually distinct by using a different `color_scheme` in each one.